# audio.play() and more than one effect playback?

Tags: javascript, audio

```
var shots = Math.ceil(Math.random(0,1)*5);
var snd = new Audio("test.wav");

for (var i = 0; i < shots; i++){
snd.play();
}
```

Now, depending on how many "shots" are fired, i want to play the test.wav the same number of times with a randomized, very short delay in between and possible even "overlapping" sound effect in regards to each other.

How would i best go about doing this ?
- thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like ...

```
var shots = Math.ceil(Math.random()*5), // Math.random() --> always 0-1 range
    src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Beatles_eleanor_rigby.ogg',  // change to your source
    maxStartTime = 1000; 
for(var i=0;i<shots;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        (new Audio(src)).play();
    }, 100 + maxStartTime*(Math.random())); // again you can calibrate the timeout value to what suits you best
}
```